# Gutenberg : image block link to media file by default

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to using WordPress 5 Gutenberg editor.

Each time I insert an image block, I have to manually change the block settings so that the image would link to the media file, to get a full definition image.

Is it possible to change this settings as a default setting, so that each time I add an image to an article, it will, by default, link to the media file ?

Comment: I looks like this is an open question that devs are working .on and users are trying to get the devs to prioritize. See [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/image_default_link_type-doesnt-work/) and [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327396/set-default-image-link-target-in-gutenberg-image-block).